# What are the application of "completing the square" method?

Tags: big-list, completing-the-square

I am trying to convince my students that "completing the square" method is widely used in mathematics.

Here is my effort, could you add other applications to my list?

1. Finding the maximum or minimum value of $ax^2+bx+c$.
2. Solving quadratic equations $ax^2+bx+c=0$.
3. Finding the characteristic of a conic section (such as center, major/minor axes, radius, etc) $Ax^2+Bx+Cy^2+Dy+E=0$.
4. Evaluating $\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{ax^2+bx+c}$.
5. Factorizing polynomial, for example $x^4+64=(x^2-4x+8)(x^2+4x+8)$.
6. Finding inverse Laplace of, for example, $\frac{s+1}{s^2+4s+10}$.

Comment: It seems to me that it's rather factorization of polynomials which is widely used and that "completing the square" is just one special case.

Comment: Basically everywhere. It's harder to find a place where it can't be used.

Comment: @mathreadler: for example?

Comment: I think, the list you created is convincing enough already.

Comment: @WellHarassedProgrammer actually I can't even think of a place where it can't be used.

Comment: @mathreadler: Do you think there are some non-trivial applications  of it in graph theory, combinatorics, linear algebra, discrete mathematics, etc?

Comment: "Non trivial application". Hahahaha. It is everywhere. I can't think of any of the theorems in the courses I have read which does not have it.

Comment: @mathreadler: Show me the applications. Hahahaha...

Comment: Few more topics in here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square

Comment: I think it's more economical to convince them of the importance of squares (or, in other words, nonnegative numbers). Then this follows from that.

Comment: some students have trouble with completing the square to solve $P^T H P = D,$ where all are square matrices, $H$ is symmetric and $D$ is to be diagonal... see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr